# Picketlink 2.6+ Jboss AS 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, server, picketlink

I was wondering if it was possible to use picketlink 2.6 or newer on jboss as 7.1.1?

The installer says only eap or wildfly, but I am forced to use as7 so that doesn't work for me...

Is it a case of installing the modules myself, or does it just not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I got it working by moving the jars over to the modules folder manually and editing the modules.xml files respectively for each one. A bit time consuming but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but I think we were running some actual version of PicketLink on 7.something. Not sure at the moment.

But we never used an installer, we were doing it via [modules](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUpdateJBossAS7ToNewerVersionsOfPicketLink) and `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/html/Referencing_PicketLink_from_JBoss_Modules.html):

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- This will enable PicketLink Federation to your deployment. -->
            <module name="org.picketlink" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: yeah I think I will just have to change the module xml files and replace the jars myself. Didn't know I had to use a deployment structure though so thanks for that :)